# Image viewer with "tags" feature?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers, tag

is there an image viewer available for Ubuntu that allows to assign "tags" (like "sport", "car", "river", "drawing" etc.) to any image in a directory and quickly filter that directory, containing a lot of images (about 5000 of them), by these tags so that I can view only images that have a particular tag or set of tags assigned?

I guess it can be partially achieved using "labels", "categories" or "keywords" that are used for example by gThumb, but these are stored in image metadata in "XMP" fields. I want the "tag" feature to be completely independent from image metadata so that tags are neither read from nor written to image files. Some images already contain some "labels" there, which are automatically read by gThumb, but they are not useful to me and I don't want them, and I certainly don't want the image files to be modified. So I'm looking for something that stores "tags" completely independent from image metadata.

Does such an application exist? Can anybody recommend anything?